# Метод POST после логина через Spring Security

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, request, spring-security

Есть страница логина. Делаю логин со spring security.

login.jsp:

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

 <h1 align="center">Log in</h1>

 <div id="login-box">

  <h3>Enter your user name and password</h3>

  <c:if test="${not empty error}">
   <div class="error">${error}</div>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
   <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
  </c:if>

  <form name='loginForm'
   action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>User:</td>
     <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Password:</td>
     <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
      value="Авторизоваться" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}" />

  </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

home.jsp

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="false"%>
<html>
<body>
 <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
 <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
   value="${_csrf.token}" />
 </form>
 <script>
  function formSubmit() {
   document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
  }
 </script>

 <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
  <h2>
   Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
    href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
  </h2>
 </c:if>
 
 <a href="test">Go test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Custom Login Form");
    model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
    model.setViewName("home");

    return model;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;

}
```

После, со страницы home.jsp переходим по ссылке на какую-нибудь страницу, с которой потом нужно отправить submit методом POST.

Например test.jsp:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>${test}</h1>
 <form action="test2" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="message">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 
 <a href="home">Go home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Выскакивает exception**

> HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Работает только передача методом GET. Как можно избавиться от этого?

Comment: csrf токен надо передавать во всех запросах, а не только при логине. Ну либо выключить эту функциональность вообще, но это не самая лучшая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Vartlok за комментарий. Он очень помог и я нашел ошибку. Действительно, spring security требует передачи токена во всех запросах. Проблема решается довольно просто. При сабмите передаем еще `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />` и все работает.